# Strange result when using squeryl and scala

Tags: scala, one-to-many, squeryl

I'm trying to select the coupled user by getting the correct linkedAccount.
The query that is created is correct but when trying to use a property
on dbuser e.g `dbuser.lastName` I get a compile error since dbuser is not
of type User but Query1 size=?
It's probably something really simple but I can't figure it out since I'm
a scala and squeryl noob!

Why doesn't it return the correct value and what have I done wrong in my query?
Also, saving works without any issues.

**User:**

```
class User(
            @Column("id") val id: Long,
            @Column("first_name") val firstName : String,
            @Column("last_name") val lastName : String,
            @Column("email") val email : String,
            @Column("email_validated") val emailValidated: Boolean = false,
            @Column("last_login") val lastLogin: Timestamp = null,
            val created: Timestamp,
            val modified: Timestamp,
            val active: Boolean = false
                 ) extends KeyedEntity[Long] {

  lazy val linkedAccounts: OneToMany[LinkedAccount] = AppDB.usersToLinkedAccounts.left(this)
}
```

**LinkedAccount:**

```
class LinkedAccount(
                     @Column("id") val id: Long,
                     @Column("user_id") val userId: Long,
                     @Column("provider_user_id") val providerUserId: String,
                     @Column("salt") val salt: String,
                     @Column("provider_key") val providerKey: String) extends KeyedEntity[Long] {

  lazy val user: ManyToOne[User] = AppDB.usersToLinkedAccounts.right(this)

}
```

**AppDB:**

```
object AppDB extends Schema {
  val users = table[User]("users")
  val linkedAccounts = table[LinkedAccount]("linked_account")
  val usersToLinkedAccounts = oneToManyRelation(users, linkedAccounts).via((u, l) => u.id === l.userId)

def userByLinkedAccount(prodivderKey: String, providerUserId: String) = {
    from(AppDB.users)(u =>
      where(u.id in
        from(AppDB.linkedAccounts)(la =>
          where(la.userId === u.id and la.providerKey === prodivderKey and la.providerUserId === providerUserId)
            select (la.userId)
        )
      )
        select (u)
    )    
  }
```

**The call:**

```
val dbuser = inTransaction {
      val u2 = AppDB.userByLinkedAccount(id.providerId, id.id)
      println(u2.statement)              
    }
     println(dbuser.lastName)
```

**The sql generated**

```
Select
  users10.last_login as users10_last_login,
  users10.email as users10_email,
  users10.modified as users10_modified,
  users10.last_name as users10_last_name,
  users10.first_name as users10_first_name,
  users10.id as users10_id,
  users10.created as users10_created,
  users10.email_validated as users10_email_validated,
  users10.active as users10_active
From
  users users10
Where
  (users10.id in ((Select
     linked_account13.user_id as linked_account13_user_id
   From
     linked_account linked_account13
   Where
     (((linked_account13.user_id = users10.id) and (linked_account13.provider_key = 'facebook')) and (linked_account13.provider_user_id = 'XXXXXXXXXX'))
  ) ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out. I need to make the call, in this case:

```
.headOption
```

Also fixed the query after some tips from Per

```
def userByLinkedAccount(providerKey : String, providerUserId : String) = {
    inTransaction {
      from(AppDB.users, AppDB.linkedAccounts)((u,la) =>
        where (u.id === la.userId and la.providerKey === providerKey and la.providerUserId === providerUserId)
          select(u)
      ).headOption
    }
  }
```

Comment: You may want to consider using `headOption` instead, which in your case will return an `Option[User]`. Be careful using `single` as it will throw an exception if there is no data (or more than one row is returned).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, in the documentation to `@Column` and `@ColumnBase` it is said:

> The preferred way to define column metadata is not not define them (!)

So, you can define columns just as

`val id: Long,`

instead of

`@Column("id") val id: Long`

Comment: Aha! Thank you for the tips!